# Asking for user input more than once in a while loop

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, input, while-loop

I am currently writing a program that translates normal text to whale talk (in case you want to know what whale talk is, it is the statement ripped of consonants with u's and e's doubled)

I successfully wrote the program. But I want it to be repeated again and go through the same process until we manually exit it.

For this I used a while loop and used exit as variable. But it didn't work as expected as on second time around it did not ask for input but displayed the prompt text and skipped to the exit/no exit line.
Can you tell me what is wrong with my program? Here is my code (you can try to compile and execute it yourself):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(){
  bool exit = false;
//Open
std::cout<<"==========\n";
std::cout<<"WHALE TALK\n";
std::cout<<"==========\n";
std::cout<<"\n";
//main loop

while (!exit){

//Variables
std::vector<char> whaletalk;
//input
std::string input;
std::cout<<"Type the text you want to translate to whale language: ";
getline(std::cin,input);
std::cout<<"\n\nWhale talk: ";

//vowels
std::vector <char> vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u'};

//sorter
//iterating through string
for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){
  //iterating through vowels
  for (int j = 0; j < vowels.size(); j++){
      //case of vowels
      if(input[i] == vowels[j]){
          //case of u and e
          if ((input[i] == 'u') or (input[i] == 'e')){
              whaletalk.push_back(input[i]);
              whaletalk.push_back(input[i]);
          }
          //case of vowels other than u and e
          else {whaletalk.push_back(input[i]);}
      }
  }
}
//Output
for (int k = 0; k < whaletalk.size(); k++ ){

  std::cout<<whaletalk[k];
}
std::cout<<"\n";
// exit/no exit
std::string response;
std::cout<<'\n';
std::cout<<"Do you have more to translate?(yes/no)\n\nYour response: ";
std::cin>>response;
if (response == "NO" or response == "no" or response == "No"){
  exit = true;
}




}
}
```

[Here is an image of the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVzbc.png)

Comment: This blog post might be a good start for you: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @ThomasSablik oh, thanks :) I didn't know that! I will delete my comment to not confuse others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `>>` operator to read a string, it only reads the next word (up to a whitespace character), and leaves everything else on the input stream, but `std::cin` still blocks until a new line (enter is pressed).

> ```
> std::string response;
> std::cout << '\n';
> std::cout << "Do you have more to translate?(yes/no)\n\nYour response: ";
> std::cin >> response;
> if (response == "NO" or response == "no" or response == "No") {
>     exit = true;
> ```

This leaves just the newline in the buffer if you only typed one word (if you did say "a b" then it would leave "b\n" and `response` would be "a", not "a b"), and so the next `std::getline` will give you what was left, in this case an empty line.

```
int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::cout << "Enter word: ";
    std::cin >> str;
    std::cout << "Entered '" << str << "'" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Enter line: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    std::cout << "Entered '" << str << "'" << std::endl;
}
```

> ```
> Enter word: a
> Entered 'a'
> Enter line: Entered ''
> ```

Or if you have a space character:

> ```
> Enter word: aa bb
> Entered 'aa'
> Enter line: Entered ' bb'
> ```

You could just always use `std::getline` when reading just string responses to avoid missing anything by accident (like that " bb").

```
 std::string response;
 std::cout << '\n';
 std::cout << "Do you have more to translate?(yes/no)\n\nYour response: ";
 std::getline(std::cin, response);
 if (response == "NO" or response == "no" or response == "No") {
     exit = true;
```

Or after any other `>>` operations to get whatever is "remaining" and proceed to the next line.

Another possibility is to use `std::istream.ignore()` to ignore remaining input up to a maxmium length and delimiter:

```
 std::string response;
 std::cout << '\n';
 std::cout << "Do you have more to translate?(yes/no)\n\nYour response: ";
 std::cin >> response;
 std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
 if (response == "NO" or response == "no" or response == "No") {
     exit = true;
```

In this case `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` means any amount, up to the next line `\n`. If the user entered say "no abc", then "abc" would be lost.

Comment: True, there are a few ways that come to mind. Were you thinking of any others?

Comment: Not really - I was going to post a much shorter answer with a simple `ignore()` call, but that would have been nowhere near as good as yours. Since your edit, it's now a near-faultless answer! +1

Comment: Sir, can you explain like what was going on when I typed "yes" to response? Due to my unfamiliarity with coding I found it difficult to understand, moreover I tend to understand faster through examples like the "aa bb" case. It would be a big of a help if you explained what happened after I typed "yes" to the std::cin>>response. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Wait after reading your answer for a few times I think I understood why i was wrong.Here is my assumption. I used the std::cin to get the input. But as you have said, after I typed 'yes' the std::cin took 'yes' from the input stream but left a line(\n) behind. This line was sucked up by the initial input (type the text you want to translate) and hence remained blank and then output remained blank and hence returned to same question. If i had used getline() to gather input then it would have sucked up the line(\n) as well. Please do correct me if i am wrong. (also do say if i was right).

Comment: So after it does the `>>` in the "not no" case, it loops back to the top where the `getline` for text is, making that `getline` occur immediately after the `>>`. The `getline` will consume the newline, so that the input after it is the *next* line.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should put these function to clear input and ignore all character except break line character:

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
```

below this function:

```
std::cin >> ...;
```

2. Here is the loop check for response:

```
      while (true) {
            if (response == "NO" or response == "no" or response == "No") {
                exit = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (response == "YES" or response == "yes" or response == "Yes")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "\nPlease only input yes or no: ";
                std::cin >> response;
                // Clear input
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
            }
        }
```

3. Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    bool exit = false;
    //Open
    std::cout << "==========\n";
    std::cout << "WHALE TALK\n";
    std::cout << "==========\n";
    std::cout << "\n";
    //main loop

    while (!exit) {

        //Variables
        std::vector<char> whaletalk;
        std::cout << "Type the text you want to translate to whale language: ";
        //input
        std::string input;
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
        std::cout << "\n\nWhale talk: ";

        //vowels
        std::vector <char> vowels = { 'a','e','i','o','u' };

        //sorter
        //iterating through string
        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
            //iterating through vowels
            for (int j = 0; j < vowels.size(); j++) {
                //case of vowels
                if (input[i] == vowels[j]) {
                    //case of u and e
                    if ((input[i] == 'u') or (input[i] == 'e')) {
                        whaletalk.push_back(input[i]);
                        whaletalk.push_back(input[i]);
                    }
                    //case of vowels other than u and e
                    else { whaletalk.push_back(input[i]); }
                }
            }
        }
        //Output
        for (int k = 0; k < whaletalk.size(); k++) {

            std::cout << whaletalk[k];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
        // exit/no exit
        std::string response;
        std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << "Do you have more to translate?(yes/no)\n\nYour response: ";
        std::cin >> response;
        // Clear input
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');

        while (true) {
            if (response == "NO" or response == "no" or response == "No") {
                exit = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (response == "YES" or response == "yes" or response == "Yes")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "\nPlease only input yes or no: ";
                std::cin >> response;
                // Clear input
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sir what does the fflush(stdin) do? I haven't heard of it.Thank you in advance!